# Flutter FlatButton does not show tap animation / ripple effect

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the following code:

```
return new ListTile(
                          leading: new CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                              child: new Image.network(
                                  "http://res.cloudinary.com/kennyy/image/upload/v1531317427/avatar_z1rc6f.png")),
                          title: new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Expanded(child: new Text(message)),
                              new FlatButton(onPressed: null, child: new Text("Delete"))
                            ]
                          ),
                          subtitle: new Text(from),
                        );
```

which created a tile in my ListView.
Each tile should have a button.
When I tap the button - I don't see any ripple effect or animation that I actually clicked. I was pretty sure it's a part of the Material theme as a gesture for FlatButtons, but I tried a solution I found, using `InkWell`:

```
return new ListTile(
                          leading: new CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                              child: new Image.network(
                                  "http://res.cloudinary.com/kennyy/image/upload/v1531317427/avatar_z1rc6f.png")),
                          title: new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Expanded(child: new Text(message)),
                              InkWell(
                                  child: FlatButton(onPressed: null, child: new Text("Delete"), color: Colors.amber))
                            ]
                          ),
                          subtitle: new Text(from),
                        );
```

But still - my listview button does not have any ripple effect when tapped.

Any idea?

Comment: I think you need to wrap in in a `Material` to see ripple effects.

Comment: try to change the onPressed parameter to `(){}`?

Comment: @JeromeEscalante that was the actual issue! Thanks! it seems like when the onPressed method is `null` - the button is in `disabled` state by default.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter buttons are disabled by default. To enable a button, set its [`onPressed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton/onPressed.html) or [`onLongPress`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton/onLongPress.html) properties to a non-null value.

The ripple is not visible because you've set the property of your `onPressed` to `null`.

```
new FlatButton(onPressed: null, child: new Text("Delete"))
```

Change the onPressed property to something like this:

```
new FlatButton(onPressed: (){}, child: new Text("Delete"))
```

To compare here is an example of a no-null `onPressed` and a `null` valued `onPressed`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListTile(
        leading: new CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            child: new Image.network(
                "http://res.cloudinary.com/kennyy/image/upload/v1531317427/avatar_z1rc6f.png")),
        title: new Row(children: <Widget>[
          //new Expanded(child: new Text(message)),
          new TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: new Text("Delete"),
          ),
          new TextButton(
            onPressed: null,
            child: new Text("Delete"),
          )
        ]),
        //subtitle: new Text(from),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**Note that the [FlatButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html) is now deprecated so I've used [TextButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html) in the example.*